# Ember.js 2, many click, many relationships, how to handle many clicks?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, relationship

I have these models:

**Fight**:

```
export default Model.extend({
  teams: hasMany('team')
});
```

**Team**:

```
export default Model.extend({
  closed: attr('boolean'),
  fight: belongsTo('fight'),
  players: hasMany('player')
});
```

**Player**:

```
export default Model.extend({
  team: belongsTo('team'),
    nickname: belongsTo('nickname')
});
```

**Nickname**:

```
export default Model.extend({
  nickname: belongsTo('nickname')
});
```

Now I'm in the *fight page* and I have a *list* of all the *nicknames* and with a click on each one I need to:

- if there aren't teams already in fight (this model) I create a team and after that I insert my player in that team;
- if there is a team already in fight and is "NOT CLOSED" I simply insert my player in that last team;
- if there is a team already in fight and is "CLOSED" I need to add a new team for this new player and all others new players until that team is closed.

Everything works with this code:

```
fight.get('teams').then((all_teams) => {
    let count_teams = all_teams.get('length');

    if (count_teams > 0) {
        let last_team = all_teams.objectAt(count_teams - 1);
        if (last_team.get('closed') === false) {
            saveNewPlayer(last_team);
        } else {
            saveNewTeam();
        }
    } else {
        saveNewTeam();
    }

    function saveNewTeam() {
        let new_team = store.createRecord('team', {
            fight: fight
        });
        new_team.save().then((new_team) => {
            saveNewPlayer(new_team);
        }).catch(() => {
            new_team.rollbackAttributes();
        });
    }

    function saveNewPlayer(last_team) {
        let newPlayer = store.createRecord('player', {
            team: last_team
        });
        newPlayer.save().then(() => {
            // handle aftersave
        }).catch(() => {
            newPlayer.rollbackAttributes();
        });
    }

});
```

**But there is a problem when the internet connection with server is slow.**

If I click many nicknames the code checks the actual status of the fight, it says: "*No teams open (available) here, I need a new one*" and as you can imagine (because internet is crappy) it creates a lot of teams with just one player, as many as I clicked each of nicknames.

How can I fix this?

I need something like a queue?

Maybe I can click one player and then during the check if I click again I can queue the next player? But I need to show instantly the list of players added.

How to?

Comment: This kind of logic is best kept on the server (determining if a new team is needed).  You would have the same problems if another user was attempting it at the same time.  Let the server decide if a new team is needed.

Comment: Thanks steve, and how to handle in the meantime the new players? Because I need to compose the list instantly...

Answer (score 0):

To prevent sending lots of requests to the server, you should better to prevent the next requests. There are alternatives such as disabling the button, ignoring the next actions etc.

We are using [ember-concurrency](https://ember-concurrency.com/) addon for such use cases. It clearly drops the next actions.

Comment: Thanks @ykaragol, but how to handle in the meantime the new players? Because I need to compose and show the list instantly...

Comment: Is it a problem for user? You may put a loading spinner?